# How to use numbers as delimiters in MATLAB strsplit function

Tags: matlab

As the title suggests I'm looking to detect where the numbers are in a string and then to just take the substring from the larger string. EG

If I have say zero89 or eight78, I would just like zero or nine returned. When using the strsplit function I have:

```
strsplit('zero89', but what do I put here?)
```

Comment: "zero" or "nine" returned from zero89 or eight78? Where is "nine" in these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interested in [**`regexp`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) that will provide you more options to explore with?

Extract numeric digits -

```
regexp('zero89','\d','match')
```

Extract anything other than digits -

```
regexp('zero89','\d+','Split')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strsplit('zero89', '\d', 'DelimiterType', 'RegularExpression')
```

Or just using `regexp`:

```
regexp('zero89','\D+','match')
```

I got the `\D+` from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1610098.aspx?Regex+Split+extract+only+first+number+form+a+string)

Comment: It should be noted that `strsplit` is simply a wrapper for `regexp`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean this [strsplit](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21710-string-toolkits/content/strings/strsplit.m)?

```
strsplit('zero89', '8')
```

Comment: This will fail on the second example. I think the OP wants the characters before any integer.